# Stuck in ttyl after installing chrome remote desktop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, remote-desktop

I had installed chrome remote desktop onto my ubuntu 22.04 machine, following this guide:
https://cloud.google.com/architecture/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine#install_an_x_windows_system_desktop_environment for gnome. Now, I'm stuck in ttyl and I've tried sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop, to no avail. Also, the machine is dualbooted with Windows 11. Any help?